# Authorization has been denied for this request (Skype REST API)

Tags: python, api, postman, botframework, skype

Good evening, community experts.

I was integrating my application with Skype using the REST API (Bot Framework). Everything worked perfectly until today.
In the morning, while checking the functionality of the application, I noticed that the bot's response did not displayed in Skype. I decided to send a message through «Postman», and I received the following response:

```
{
    "message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

I thought there might be a problem with token. Through the request below, I got a new one, but it didn't help:

```
curl -k -X POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<APP ID>&client_secret=<APP PASWORD>&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default"
```

Here are my «Postman» POST HTTPS query settings:

```
URL:
https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations/<CONVERSATION ID>/activities/<MESSAGE ID>

HEADERS:
Postman-Token: <calculated when request is sent>
Content-Lenght: <calculated when request is sent>
Host: <calculated when request is sent>
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer 0SzRndyIsImtpZCI6ImppYk5ia0ZTU2JteFBZck45Q0...

BODY:
{
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
        "id": <BOT ID>,
        "name": <BOT NAME>
    },
   "recipient": {
        "id": <USER ID>,
        "name": <USER NAME>
    },
    "text": <MESSAGE>
}
```

Please tell me what the problem might be? Everything worked fine yesterday! Could there be a problem with the SSL certificate? Or should the Authorization parameter be passed in some other way? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This issue appears to be specific to Skype, most likely with the `https://smba.trafficmanager.net` endpoint. Skype deprecated bots on their service not that long ago and they have been winding down their own bots since then. Additionally, it's impossible to create new bots on Skype. My guess is they recently updated or changed something that now affected you. I don't know how actively they monitor this email, but you can try contacting them at **skypebotsupport@microsoft.com**.

Comment: @StevenKanberg Hello! Thanks for the answer.
Unfortunately, I faced the problem of inability to send a letter to skypebotsupport@microsoft.com due to the fact that the skypebotsupport group only accepts messages from people in its organization or on its allowed senders list, and my email address isn't on the list.

Comment: There is a Skype forum, located [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum), that looks quite active. I don't know if anyone from MS joins in there, but you may find additional guidance there from the community.